# Output text changes based on two drop down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically I am trying to make a page where the user can select options from two drop down menus, when the second drop down menu has been completed and both have options in them I want it to trigger some javascript that takes those values and then returns text depending on the output.

E.g. a user selects xbox and comfort trade, the price is returned as £5, or maybe they select playstation and comfort trade, the price is returned as £2.50, or maybe they want pc and player auction the price is only £0.99.

**HTML**

```
<select id="platform" name="platform">
    <option select value=""></option>
    <option value="xbox">Xbox</option>
    <option value="playstation">PlayStation</option>
    <option value="pc">PC</option>
</select><br>
<p>Select Method:</p>
<select id="method" name="method" onChange="price()">
    <option selected value=""></option>
    <option value="comfortTrade">Comfort Trade</option>
    <option value="playerAuction">Player Auction</option>
</select><br>
<h3 id="price"></h3>
```

**Javascript**

```
function price() {
    if ($(document.getElementById("platform")) === "xbox" && $(document.getElementById("method")) === "comfortTrade") {
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "£5";
    } else if ($(document.getElementById("platform")) === "playstation" && $(document.getElementById("method")) === "comfortTrade") {
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "£2.50";
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to Javascript but I had a go at doing this, I also have spent the past hour or so trying to search for tutorials on this but nothing got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this javascript function:

```
function price() {
    if (document.getElementById("platform").value == "xbox" && document.getElementById("method").value == "comfortTrade") {
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "£5";
    } else if (document.getElementById("platform").value == "playstation" && document.getElementById("method").value == "comfortTrade") {
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "£2.50";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things need to be updated in the existing code to get this to work:

1) `onchange` has no capital letters, and needs to be added to "platform" `<select>` as well

2) no need for `$` here, can simply use `document.getElementById`

3) after selecting the element in step 2, will need to get the value of the select by accessing the property `.value` on the element.

Fixed code:

```
<div id="app">
  <select id="platform" name="platform" onchange="price()">
    <option select value=""></option>
    <option value="xbox">Xbox</option>
    <option value="playstation">PlayStation</option>
    <option value="pc">PC</option>
  </select><br>
  <p>Select Method:</p>
  <select id="method" name="method" onchange="price()">
    <option selected value=""></option>
    <option value="comfortTrade">Comfort Trade</option>
    <option value="playerAuction">Player Auction</option>
  </select><br>
  <h3 id="price"></h3>
</div>

<script>
  function price() {
    if(document.getElementById("platform").value === "xbox" && document.getElementById("method").value === "comfortTrade") {
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "£5";
    } else if(document.getElementById("platform").value === "playstation" && document.getElementById("method").value === "comfortTrade") {
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "£2.50";
    } 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have jQuery installed because you are using `$(...)` in your code, you can solve your issue like this:

```
    <select id="platform" name="platform" onchange="findPrice()">
        <option select value=""></option>
        <option value="xbox">Xbox</option>
        <option value="playstation">PlayStation</option>
        <option value="pc">PC</option>
    </select><br>
    <p>Select Method:</p>
    <select id="method" name="method" onchange="findPrice()">
        <option selected value=""></option>
        <option value="comfortTrade">Comfort Trade</option>
        <option value="playerAuction">Player Auction</option>
    </select><br>
    <h3 id="price"></h3>
<script type="application/javascript">
window.findPrice = function() {
    if($("#platform").val() === "xbox" && $("#method").val() === "comfortTrade") {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "£5";
    }else if($("#platform").val() === "playstation" && $("#method").val() === "comfortTrade") {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "£2.50";
    }
}
</script>
```

You can see a working example of this at: https://jsfiddle.net/L2vgqmtL/

---

However, I would actually propose a slightly different solution that I find more elegant:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
window.findPrice = function() {
  var platform = $("#platform").val();
  var method = $("#method").val();
  var priceUpdateText = "";
    if(method == 'comfortTrade'){
    switch(platform){
        case "xbox":
        priceUpdateText = "£5";
        break;
      case "playstation":
        priceUpdateText = "£2.50";
        break;
      default:
        priceUpdateText = "";
    }
  }
  $("#price").text(priceUpdateText);
}
</script>
            <select id="platform" name="platform" onchange="findPrice()">
        <option select value=""></option>
        <option value="xbox">Xbox</option>
        <option value="playstation">PlayStation</option>
        <option value="pc">PC</option>
    </select><br>
    <p>Select Method:</p>
    <select id="method" name="method" onchange="findPrice()">
        <option selected value=""></option>
        <option value="comfortTrade">Comfort Trade</option>
        <option value="playerAuction">Player Auction</option>
    </select><br>
    <h3 id="price"></h3>
```

A working example of this solution is available here: https://jsfiddle.net/8wafskbw/2/

**Important Note:** *Both of these solutions operate under the presumption that have jQuery included in your page.*